# Move navigation drawer icon (hamburger)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-tablayout, drawerlayout

I need to move navigation drawer icon (hamburger) from action bar to tab layout to make it look like provided for example. That should be performed on list scroll. Is there any possibility to move views from action bar to tab layout?

**Action bar**
[image: Action bar]

**Expected result**
[image: Expected result]

Comment: you can use a custom tab view which is a imageview then on image click action call     a method that opens your left menu

Comment: Maybe implementing Toolbar

Answer (score 1):

You can include a tabLayout in a toolbar like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```